# Remove weird white space between nested divs on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

How can you remove the weird white space between two nested divs on Chrome.

```
<div class="bar">
    <div class="progress">
    </div>
</div>

.bar {
 width: 200px;
  height: 6px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.progress {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: black;
}
```

Here is the link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hfob7yz4/1/.

On Chrome it looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0AZO.png) for me with the weird margin.
On Firefox it looks pretty normal like expected:
[firefox-img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw0od.png)

It also depends on the screen width. The problem only shows up on my laptop.

Thanks

Comment: check your zoom level

Comment: On the big screen it looks on zoom weird too your right. But on the laptop it's also on normal 100% weird

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that there is a border around the main div, and gets visible on some screens
to avoid this add

```
.bar {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[read more here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp)

Comment: It just shrinks the size of the bar for me

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting a sort of edge effect when on different zoom levels - there are bits of pixel 'left behind' in the system's calculations as it tries to map part CSS pixels to the several screen pixels that might make up a CSS pixel on modern screens.

Instead of needing a second, inner div, you could paint the progress with a background image using a linear-gradient - this can be altered by JS dynamically as  required.

```css
.bar {
  --progress: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 6px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 0 var(--progress), transparent var(--progress) 100%);
}


}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
</div>
```

Comment: That looks like it's doing it. I will try it in the app. But thanks :)

Comment: Now in some cases it does not fill the whole bar even with 100% progress or it leaves a small gap before starting the progress on firefox.